# How to get Custom Post Type with Categories wise in WordPress using wp_query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, categories

```
$args = array(
    //'post_type' => 'article',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'category'     => 'starter',
    'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                'key' => 'recommended_article',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => '=='
                    )
                )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while($query->have_posts()){
    the_content();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is **very** unclear (given that you don't actually ask a question), but there are 2 problems with your code, both of which are corrected below:

```
    $args = array (
    //'post_type' => 'article',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'category_name' => 'starter', // changed from 'category' to 'category_name'
    'meta_query' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'recommended_article',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '=', // changed from '==' to '='
            ),
        ),
    ) ;
$query = new WP_Query ($args) ;
while ($query->have_posts ()) {
    the_content () ;
    }
```

For the details of *why* these changes are necessary, see [WP_Query, Category Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) and [WP_Query, Custom Field Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: Hi I created a custom post like product .I want to display all  categorises  and their posts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have try this way and worked for me

```
$terms =  get_terms( array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'hide_empty' => true,
                        'orderby'=> 'name',
                        'order'=>'ASC'
                    ));

                    foreach( $terms as $term){
                        $termChildren = get_term_children($term->term_id, 'category');
                              $args = array('post_type' => 'mycustompost',
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                                'orderby'   => 'ID',
                                'order' => 'ASC',
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $term->slug
                                    ),                                                  
                                )
                            );
                            $query = new WP_Query($args);
                            while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
                                  the_title(); the_content();
                            endwhile;
                     }
```